# List style article in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, field, custom-fields

I'm trying to create a content type that allows me to post multiple images from an external database in this sort of style: http://www.newageman.co.uk/14-time-travelling-celebrities

In an ideal world this is what I would like my group of fields to look like in the article creation screen.
http://oi57.tinypic.com/wi0z8i.jpg

Any idea how I would achieve this using best practices? To post articles like this I'm currently using a piece of php code but it's confusing for my contributors, so would like to use fields. I've never made a module or custom field before.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar using the [Field Group module](https://drupal.org/project/field_group), you may give it a try.

Comment: Thank you zerospace, I tried that but found the field collection module to be better suited to achieve what I was looking for. https://drupal.org/project/field_collection